# How to highlight text in label based on textbox value?

Tags: html, angularjs, textbox

How can I highlight a text based on some value entered into textbox .

For example , if there is label with text 'Hello' and the user types 'He' , then label becomes **He** llo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular UI has directive just for that

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/highlight